# How to make div height and width to full screen with specific margin without scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have div that create a box in browser with same height and width of it and having 5px margins around the edges. [image: Suppose green border is the browser size, then I want to achieve a silver box for my content]

I tried to achieve via following code

```
div#welcome {
    height: 100vh;
    border: 2px green;
}

div#welcome2 {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit; 
    background: silver;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

}

<div id="welcome">
    <div id="welcome2">
    </div>
</div>
```

But it always appears with the scroll bar.

[image]

That should not be the case. I want to achieve it as a full-size container with margin of 20px all the side of browser without scroll bar.

Comment: @Temani, undoubtedly, this question has been asked before. But if you mark it as duplicate, at least do it right. Absolutely nowhere in this question has OP asked for *"not using CSS3 calc"* and you have marked it as a duplicate of a question which is very specific in that regard, for some reason.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu we don't close question because of its title .. both question deal with the same issue and the other one simply has an additionnal requirement but at the end the goal is the same and all the solutions apply here. calc() is only one way among many to achieve this.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu in other words, if the OP found that duplicate he can easily achieve what he wants with or without calc() thus it's a duplicate.

Comment: I really don't dispute your decision to close it as duplicate. Should have done it myself but it seemed simpler to answer than find a duplicate (and I'm lazy). Ref being the same question: it's obvious to me and you, as we're experienced, but not so obvious to beginners. In other words, I'm pretty sure the *"without using calc"* part of the linked question is an XY problem to begin with, which makes your decision **right**, but we should at least add a more *"proper"* duplicate to this one. I'll see to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Option 2: use transparent border, [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) and [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```css
body { margin: 0; }

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Like that calc way, nevertheless its hard sometime to have that 20px fixed coded

Comment: note that defining width is useless since it's by default full width

Comment: @TemaniAfif, agreed, if it does not have a `position` set to `absolute` or `fixed`, which is a common case for modals & overlays. I thought being verbose is best in this case, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using width and height for your div will only set the content size. To that size you have to add margin, border and padding.

There is `box-sizing` available in css. You can set this to `border-box`, which will let padding and border be included in the `width` and `height`.